# Why won't my CoffeeScript if/else statement work?

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript

I've been trying to update a total price when someone changes the select option. Here is the select element I'm using:

```
<select id="payment_talks_purchased" name="payment[talks_purchased]">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Three</option>
</select>
```

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var price = $(".total-price span.price")
  var save = $(".savings")
  $("#payment_talks_purchased").change(function() {
    var selection = $("#payment_talks_purchased").val()
    if (selection == 2) {
      price.html("$12");
      save.css("visibility", "visible");
    } else if (selection == 1) {
      price.html("$5");
      save.css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  });  
});
```

It works perfectly. It changes the price to $12 and shows the discount message. If I change the select option back to One/1, it changes the text back to $5 and removes the discount message.

I converted this to CoffeeScript but it only works when I make the first change. The price is updated. However, when I try to change it back to option 1, it doesn't update.

```
jQuery ->
  price = $(".total-price span.price")
  save = $(".savings")
  select = $("#payment_talks_purchased")
  select.change ->
    selection = select.val()
    if selection = 2
      price.html "$12"
      return save.css "visibility", "visible"
    else if selection = 1
      price.html "$5"
      return save.css "visibility", "hidden"
```

I've been working on this for hours and am at my wits end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `selection = 1` inside your `if` statements is (still) an assignment in CoffeeScript, you need to use `==` for comparison. Try this:

```
jQuery ->
  price = $(".total-price span.price")
  save = $(".savings")
  select = $("#payment_talks_purchased")
  select.change ->
    selection = select.val()
    if selection == '2'
      price.html "$12"
      return save.css "visibility", "visible"
    else if selection == '1'
      price.html "$5"
      return save.css "visibility", "hidden"
```

Also, [`==` is converted to `===`](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#operators) so you'll want to compare against strings unless you want to "cast" your value to a number using `selection = +select.val()` (thanks to [Trevor Burnham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66226/trevor-burnham) for this casting trick) or `parseInt(select.val(), 10)`.

Comment: Exactly right. Use `selection = +select.val()` if you do want to convert the form input into a number.

Comment: Isn't `is` preferred for comparison, unless you explicitly want to trigger type coercion?

Comment: @jpmc26 `is` is equivalent to `==` in CoffeeScript so both end up as `===` in the final JavaScript version. There is no equivalent to JavaScript's `==` in CoffeeScript so no coercion issues.

Answer (score 6):

You can use switch:

```
switch selection
  when '2'
    price.html "$12"
    save.css "visibility", "visible"
  when '1'
    price.html "$5"
    save.css "visibility", "hidden"
```

Also you can take away `return`, because functions will always return their final value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my .50 cents. Take in consideration 2 things: its just my simple opinion and it can be not the best answer of the world.

a) If you already have a return inside IF statement, no need ELSE IF

```
jQuery ->
price = $(".total-price span.price")
save = $(".savings")
select = $("#payment_talks_purchased")
select.change ->
    selection = select.val()
    if selection == '2'
        price.html "$12"
        // Since you return here, you dont need any other "else if"
        return save.css "visibility", "visible"

    price.html "$5"
    return save.css "visibility", "hidden"
```

And no, IMHO, puts the ELSE IF doesnt improve the readability. Return is a return. Period. It is simple as that.

```
jQuery ->
price = $(".total-price span.price")
save = $(".savings")
select = $("#payment_talks_purchased")
select.change ->
    selection = select.val()
    // "ternary" coffee version (if then else)
    price.html if selection == '2' then "$12" else "$5")
    save.css "visibility" (if selection == '2' then "visible" else "hidden")
```

But, better than all is get rid of IF, ELSE, SWITCH and all those craps. Think OOP and your code can start getting better. A starting point could be:

```
options = [
             {price: '$12', visible:"visible"}, 
             {price: '$5', visible:"hidden"}
          ];
jQuery ->
    price = $(".total-price span.price")
    save = $(".savings")
    select = $("#payment_talks_purchased")
    select.change ->
              // If the val of your select was 0 and 1, you wouldnt need the (-1) part
      selection = parseInt(select.val) -1
              price.html options[selection].price
              save.css "visibility" options[selection].visible
```

So, this is it. Almost the same code, but with a better implementation (imho). Thank you.